# Android BLE Write large file using RxAndroidBle in blocking way

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rx-java2, rxandroidble

I have an Android App using RxAndroidBle as BLE solution which is really great and save tons of working hour.

But recently I have to implement an update firmware feature and I'm getting stuck.

One of the custom BLE devices has to wait for notification ByteAray before writing. Every 16 packages(20 bytes per package) the device will send a notification ByteAray to certain characteristics.

So what I'm trying to do is to wait for the notification, then send those firmware packages. And I found that I have to add a timer 160ms so that the device won't get overwhelmed by those packages(Backpressure?).

Still no luck. The device will go no response then disconnected after a certain amount of data, like at 256 bytes * 12(file size range from 256 bytes * 330 ~ 785).

This is the current implementation:

```
 .flatMap { ifFrameCountAccepted ->
                if (ifFrameCountAccepted) {
                    Timber.d("Wait 2 seconds cleaning up flash")
                    Flowable
                        .timer(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .flatMap { sendFramesFlowable(firmware, isPic) }
                } else {
                    Flowable.error(RuntimeException("MCU L2 frame count error."))
                }
            }
            .toObservable()
            .flatMap { isFirmwareTransmissionDone ->
                if (isFirmwareTransmissionDone) {
                    waitUntilL2McuUpgradeFinish(isPic)
                } else {
                    Observable.just(false)
                }
            }
```

```
    private fun sendFramesFlowable(
        firmware: FirmwareUpgradeData,
        isPic: Boolean
    ): Flowable<Boolean> {
        Timber.d("Firmware size: ${firmware.processed.size}")

        val frameInvalidPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create<Boolean>()
            val frameObservable = connection.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER).flatMap { rxConnection ->
            rxConnection.setupNotification(
                RC_NOTIFICATION_CHARACTERISTIC,
                NotificationSetupMode.DEFAULT
            ).toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
                .concatMap { notification ->
                    notification.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
                }
            }
                .filter { it.size == 20 }
                .filter { it.second.first().toUnsignedValue() == COMMAND_HEADER_L2_FRAME }
                .map { reply ->
                    Timber.d("[A2] decoded: ${reply.second.toHex()}")
                    val payload = reply.second.dataPayload(reply.first)
                    val isValid = upgradeDataTransmission.resolveFrameCommand(payload)
                    Timber.d("MCU L2 upgrade frame is accepted: $isValid")
                    unless(!isValid) {
                        frameInvalidPublishSubject.onNext(true)
                    }
                    isValid
                }
            .zipWith(Flowable.range(1, firmware.frameCount), BiFunction { _: Boolean, frameCount: Int ->
                frameCount
            })
            .doOnNext { frameCount ->
                val base = if (isPic) 45.minus(25) else 99.minus(45)
                val progress = base.div(firmware.frameCount.toFloat())
                    .times(frameCount).toInt()
                    .plus(if (isPic) 25 else 45)
                _upgradeProgress.postValue(Event.success(progress))
            }
            .flatMap { frameCount ->
                Timber.d("frame count now is:$frameCount")
                if (frameCount == firmware.frameCount) {
                    triggerL2Upgrade(firmware.crcCheck)
                } else {
                    Flowable.just(false)
                }
            }

        Flowable.fromIterable(firmware.processed.withIndex())
            .buffer(16)
            .takeUntil(frameInvalidPublishSubject.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER))
            .concatMap { frame ->
                Flowable.timer(160, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).concatMap {
                    Flowable.fromIterable(frame)
                        .concatMap { perPackage ->
                            connection.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
                                .concatMap {
                                    it.writeCharacteristic(RC_WRITE_CHARACTERISTIC, perPackage.value.toByteArray())
                                        .toFlowable()
                                }
                        }
                }
            }
            .forEachWhile {
                true
            }

        return frameObservable
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in helper in `RxAndroidBle` for such situations:
[`RxBleConnection.createLongWriteBuilder()`](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/blob/cb2690615c6c8babd6e1a0736473c8c429f6de04/rxandroidble/src/main/java/com/polidea/rxandroidble2/RxBleConnection.java#L443)

You can [read what exact possibilities it gives you](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/blob/cb2690615c6c8babd6e1a0736473c8c429f6de04/rxandroidble/src/main/java/com/polidea/rxandroidble2/RxBleConnection.java#L98) but using [`writeOperationAckStrategy()`](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/blob/cb2690615c6c8babd6e1a0736473c8c429f6de04/rxandroidble/src/main/java/com/polidea/rxandroidble2/RxBleConnection.java#L172) you can postpone writing next byte array:

```kotlin
val notificationsEvery16thWrite: Observable<ByteArray> = (...)
rxBleConnection.createNewLongWriteBuilder()
    .setWriteOperationAckStrategy { writeAcks ->
        val emitEveryWriteAckApartEvery16th = writeAcks
            .scan(0 to null as Boolean?) { acc, boolean ->
                acc.first.plus(1) to boolean
            }
            .filter { it.first != 0 && it.first % 16 != 0 }
            .map { it.second!! }
        val emitEvery16thWriteAckAfterNotification = notificationsEvery16thWrite.zipWith(
            writeAcks.buffer(16), // buffer 16 writes ACKs
            BiFunction { _, writesCompleted -> writesCompleted.last() }) // use last when notification arrives
        Observable.merge(
            emitEveryWriteAckApartEvery16th,
            emitEvery16thWriteAckAfterNotification
        )
    }
```